# Products in Magento DB but not Magento Admin

Tags: database, import, products, programmatically

I created a script that imports simple products programatically. However, it appears 49 products are stuck in "limbo." They appear in the DB table "catalog_product_entity" but not within Magento's Admin Panel. Should I truncate this table? Are there any other tables I should truncate?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to TRUNCATE the table; however, I was able to delete each row in "catalog_product_entity." Deleting these rows prompted all other tables to be truncated.